# What is the most preferable time of the day to visit Times Square, Manhattan by tourists?

Tags: new-york-city, times-square

What are the most preferable time by many tourist to visit Times Square as a first time visitor?

Comment: I used to walk through Times Square every day for about a decade on my daily commute. My guess is about 15:00 in the afternoon and alternatively about 20:30 in the evening. But for me personally, it's about 05:30 to stay and watch the city awaken. What to do? Take selfies like everybody else. If Grover or Cookie Monster is there, take a selfie with them and give them a fiver.  Otherwise Times Square is a deeply personal experience and all people can provide is an OPINION. Hence close voting as 'opinion-based'.

Comment: Your question is a little bit unclear. Do you want to know (a) which times *most* tourists visit meaning the most busy times, or (b) which times the *least* tourists visit meaning the quietest times?

Comment: The time that most tourists prefer to visit. in other words the time that most activities happen and the city is live.

Answer (score 3):

To see the actual Times Square without crowds or other distractions, early-ish in the morning.  Say <9am.

To see daytime Times Square, meaning tourists (it's just a tourist trap these days), creepy (sorry, they are :) characters, shopping, and trying for discount shows, say lunch time to mid afternoon, 1pm - 3pm.

To see nighttime Times Square, meaning lights, video marquees, the scrolling new ticker and other 'entertainment', anytime after sundown or after your show.

Note, people who live and or work in NYC usually avoid Times Square if at all possible.

Source: Personal observation from a window in my building.